# Write a program whose nontermination is independent of Peano arithmetic

Tags: code-golf, open-ended-function

### Challenge

Write a program P, taking no input, such that the proposition “the execution of P eventually terminates” is [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(mathematical_logic)) of [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).

### Formal rules

(In case you are a mathematical logician who thinks the above description is too informal.)

One can, in principle, [convert](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf) some [Universal Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) *U* (e.g. your favorite programming language) into a [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) formula HALT over the variable *p*, where HALT(*p*) encodes the proposition “*U* terminates on the program ([Gödel-encoded](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoedelNumber.html) by) *p*”.  The challenge is to find *p* such that neither HALT(*p*) nor ¬HALT(*p*) can be proven in Peano arithmetic.

You may assume your program runs on an ideal machine with unlimited memory and integers/pointers big enough to access it.

### Example

To see that such programs exist, one example is a program that exhaustively searches for a Peano arithmetic proof of 0 = 1.  Peano arithmetic proves that this program halts if and only if Peano arithmetic is inconsistent.  Since Peano arithmetic [is consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof) but [cannot prove its own consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem), it cannot decide whether this program halts.

However, there are many other propositions independent of Peano arithmetic on which you could base your program.

### Motivation

This challenge was inspired by a new [paper by Yedidia and Aaronson (2016)](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2725) exhibiting a 7,918-state Turing machine whose nontermination is independent of [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), a much stronger system than Peano arithmetic.  You may be interested in its citation [22].  For this challenge, of course, you may use your programming language of choice in place of actual Turing machines.

Comment: What axiom systems may be used to prove that (a) the program does not halt, and (b) the program's non-halting is unprovable in PA?

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to require that this question contain all the needed background in mathematical logic. There's quite a bit of it, and there are links to the relevant info. It's not obfuscated, it's just a technical topic. I think it would help for accessibility to state the requirement for the code separate from the motivation involving Turing machines and to link to some example of Peano-independent statements to consider, in particular [Goodstein's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) ([related golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44453/20260))

Comment: For this to make sense, we'd need to assume the code runs on idealized machine with unlimited memory. Can we also assume the machine has arbitrary real precision?

Comment: @feersum I am not expecting an axiomatic proof of (a) and (b). Just write a program, and provide enough description/arguments/citations to be reasonably convincing that the claims are true, as you would with any other challenge. You may rely on any standardly accepted axioms and theorems that you need.

Comment: @xnor You may assume unlimited memory, and unbounded pointers with which to access it. But I don’t think it’s reasonable to assume arbitrary real precision unless your language actually provides it; in most languages, a program like `x = 1.0; while (x) { x = x / 2.0; }` will actually halt very quickly.

Comment: Is randomness allowed?

Comment: @PyRulez I won’t stop you from using your language’s hash tables just because they’re seeded randomly; randomness is fine if it doesn’t change how the program works. But you don’t get to claim that your behavior is independent of PA just because you wrote `if (random() < 0.5) while(true); else return;`.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I meant something like simulating Goodstein's theorem on random input (you can only prove that the function halts if Goodstein's theorem is true, otherwise there is some nonzero probability that it does not halt).

Comment: @PyRules As feersum pointed out in response to one of the deleted answers, “even if randomness is allowed I still don't think it works, because if you have a random process that can generate any natural number with nonzero probability, then you should be able to prove that the part of the program that chooses the random number can fail to terminate.” (This is essentially because the program can only branch on finitely much information during a particular computation step.)

Answer (score 34):

## Haskell, 838 bytes

“If you want something done, …”

```hs
import Control.Monad.State
data T=V Int|T:$T|A(T->T)
g=guard
r=runStateT
s!a@(V i)=maybe a id$lookup i s
s!(a:$b)=(s!a):$(s!b)
s@((i,_):_)!A f=A(\a->((i+1,a):s)!f(V$i+1))
c l=do(m,k)<-(`divMod`sum(1<$l)).pred<$>get;g$m>=0;put m;l!!fromEnum k
i&a=V i:$a
i%t=(:$).(i&)<$>t<*>t
x i=c$[4%x i,5%x i,(6&)<$>x i]++map(pure.V)[7..i-1]
y i=c[A<$>z i,1%y i,(2&)<$>y i,3%x i]
z i=(\a e->[(i,e)]!a)<$>y(i+1)
(i?h)p=c[g$any(p#i)h,do q<-y i;i?h$q;i?h$1&q:$p,do f<-z i;a<-x i;g$p#i$f a;c[i?h$A f,do b<-x i;i?h$3&b:$a;i?h$f b],case p of A f->c[(i+1)?h$f$V i,do i?h$f$V 7;(i+1)?(f(V i):h)$f$6&V i];V 1:$q:$r->c[i?(q:h)$r,i?(2&r:h)$V 2:$q];_->mzero]
(V a#i)(V b)=a==b
((a:$b)#i)(c:$d)=(a#i)c&&(b#i)d
(A f#i)(A g)=f(V i)#(i+1)$g$V i
(_#_)_=0<0
main=print$(r(8?map fst(r(y 8)=<<[497,8269,56106533,12033,123263749,10049,661072709])$3&V 7:$(6&V 7))=<<[0..])!!0
```

### Explanation

This program directly searches for a Peano arithmetic proof of 0 = 1.  Since PA is consistent, this program never terminates; but since PA cannot prove its own consistency, the nontermination of this program is independent of PA.

`T` is the type of expressions and propositions:

- `A P` represents the proposition ∀*x* [*P*(*x*)].
- `(V 1 :$ P) :$ Q` represents the proposition *P* → *Q*.
- `V 2 :$ P` represents the proposition ¬*P*.
- `(V 3 :$ x) :$ y` represents the proposition *x* = *y*.
- `(V 4 :$ x) :$ y` represents the natural *x* + *y*.
- `(V 5 :$ x) :$ y` represents the natural *x* ⋅ *y*.
- `V 6 :$ x` represents the natural S(*x*) = *x* + 1.
- `V 7` reprents the natural 0.

In an environment with *i* free variables, we encode expressions, propositions, and proofs as 2×2 integer matrices [1, 0; *a*, *b*], as follows:

- M(*i*, ∀*x* [*P*(*x*)]) = [1, 0; 1, 4] ⋅ M(*i*, λ*x* [P(x)])
- M(*i*, λ*x* [*F*(*x*)]) = M(*i* + 1, *F*(*x*)) where M(*j*, *x*) = [1, 0; 5 + *i*, 4 + *j*] for all *j* > *i*
- M(*i*, *P* → *Q*) = [1, 0; 2, 4] ⋅ M(*i*, *P*) ⋅ M(*i*, *Q*)
- M(*i*, ¬*P*) = [1, 0; 3, 4] ⋅ M(*i*, *P*)
- M(*i*, *x* = *y*) = [1, 0; 4, 4] ⋅ M(*i*, *x*) ⋅ M(*i*, *y*)
- M(*i*, *x* + *y*) = [1, 0; 1, 4 + *i*] ⋅ M(*i*, *x*) ⋅ M(*i*, *y*)
- M(*i*, *x* ⋅ *y*) = [1, 0; 2, 4 + *i*] ⋅ M(*i*, *x*) ⋅ M(*i*, *y*)
- M(*i*, S *x*) = [1, 0; 3, 4 + *i*] ⋅ M(*i*, *x*)
- M(*i*, 0) = [1, 0; 4, 4 + *i*]
- M(*i*, (*Γ*, *P*) ⊢ *P*) = [1, 0; 1, 4]
- M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *P*) = [1, 0; 2, 4] ⋅ M(*i*, *Q*) ⋅ M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *Q*) ⋅ M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *Q* → *P*)
- M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *P*(*x*)) = [1, 0; 3, 4] ⋅ M(*i*, λ*x* [P(x)]) ⋅ M(*i*, *x*) ⋅ [1, 0; 1, 2] ⋅ M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ ∀*x* P(x))
- M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *P*(*x*)) = [1, 0; 3, 4] ⋅ M(*i*, λ*x* [P(x)]) ⋅ M(*i*, *x*) ⋅ [1, 0; 2, 2] ⋅ M(*i*, *y*) ⋅ M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *y* = *x*) ⋅ M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *P*(*y*))
- M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ ∀*x*, *P*(*x*)) = [1, 0; 8, 8] ⋅ M(*i*, λ*x* [*Γ* ⊢ *P*(*x*)])
- M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ ∀*x*, *P*(*x*)) = [1, 0; 12, 8] ⋅ M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *P*(0)) ⋅ M(*i*, λ*x* [(*Γ*, *P*(*x*)) ⊢ *P*(S(*x*))])
- M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *P* → *Q*) = [1, 0; 8, 8] ⋅ M(*i*, (*Γ*, *P*) ⊢ *Q*)
- M(*i*, *Γ* ⊢ *P* → *Q*) = [1, 0; 12, 8] ⋅ M(*i*, (*Γ*, ¬*Q*) ⊢ ¬*P*)

The remaining axioms are encoded numerically and included in the initial environment *Γ*:

- M(0, ∀*x* [*x* = *x*]) = [1, 0; 497, 400]
- M(0, ∀*x* [¬(S(*x*) = 0)]) = [1, 0; 8269, 8000]
- M(0, ∀*x* ∀*y* [S(*x*) = S(*y*) → *x* = *y*]) = [1, 0; 56106533, 47775744]
- M(0, ∀*x* [*x* + 0 = *x*]) = [1, 0; 12033, 10000]
- M(0, ∀*y* [*x* + S(*y*) = S(*x* + *y*)]) = [1, 0; 123263749, 107495424]
- M(0, ∀*x* [*x* ⋅ 0 = 0]) = [1, 0; 10049, 10000]
- M(0, ∀*x* ∀*y* [*x* ⋅ S(*y*) = *x* ⋅ *y* + *x*]) = [1, 0; 661072709, 644972544]

A proof with matrix [1, 0; *a*, *b*] can be checked given only the lower-left corner *a* (or any other value congruent to *a* modulo *b*); the other values are there to enable composition of proofs.

For example, here is a proof that addition is commutative.

- M(0, *Γ* ⊢ ∀*x* ∀*y* [*x* + *y* = *y* + *x*]) = [1, 0; 6651439985424903472274778830412211286042729801174124932726010503641310445578492460637276210966154277204244776748283051731165114392766752978964153601068040044362776324924904132311711526476930755026298356469866717434090029353415862307981531900946916847172554628759434336793920402956876846292776619877110678804972343426850350512203833644, 14010499234317302152403198529613715336094817740448888109376168978138227692104106788277363562889534501599380268163213618740021570705080096139804941973102814335632180523847407060058534443254569282138051511292576687428837652027900127452656255880653718107444964680660904752950049505280000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]

You can verify it with the program as follows:

```
*Main> let p = A $ \x -> A $ \y -> V 3 :$ (V 4 :$ x :$ y) :$ (V 4 :$ y :$ x)
*Main> let a = 6651439985424903472274778830412211286042729801174124932726010503641310445578492460637276210966154277204244776748283051731165114392766752978964153601068040044362776324924904132311711526476930755026298356469866717434090029353415862307981531900946916847172554628759434336793920402956876846292776619877110678804972343426850350512203833644
*Main> r(8?map fst(r(y 8)=<<[497,8269,56106533,12033,123263749,10049,661072709])$p)a :: [((),Integer)]
[((),0)]
```

If the proof were invalid you would get the empty list instead.

Comment: Please explain the idea behind the matrices.

Comment: @proudhaskeller They’re just a convenient, relatively compact way of Gödel numbering all possible proof trees. You can also think of them as mixed-radix numerals that get decoded from the least-significant side using div and mod by the number of possible choices at each step.

Comment: How did you encode the induction axioms?

Comment: @PyRulez M(i, Γ ⊢ ∀x, P(x)) = [1, 0; 12, 8] ⋅ M(i, Γ ⊢ P(0)) ⋅ M(i, λx [(Γ, P(x)) ⊢ P(S(x))]) is the induction axiom.

Comment: I think you could make this smaller if you use Calculus of Constructions instead (since Calculus of Constructions has first-order logic built in, and is very small). Calculus of Constructions is about as strong as ZFC, so its consistency is surely independent of PA. To check if its consistient, you simply look for a term of an empty type.

Comment: Or some stronger theory with a simpler axiomization, such as ACA_0 or NBG.

Comment: There is a theory with only a binary relation ∈ and a single axiom schema that is mutually interpretable with PA: ∃z ∀w (w ∈ z ↔ (z ∈ x ∨ z = y) ∧ φ) where z is not free in φ. See [axiom of adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_adjunction). This seems like it could yield a shorter answer. Perhaps one could also search over proofs in [minimal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic) rather than classical logic (e.g., PA and [Heyting arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_arithmetic) are [equiconsistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equiconsistency)).